# Scala Beginner trying to use Parameterised Type

Tags: scala

I am trying to define a method using parameterised types like below..

Method Definition

```
def addNumber1[T](x:T):T = (x + 1.asInstanceOf[T])
```

But getting error as below..

And want to use it as below..

```
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: String
       def addNum[T](x:T):T = (x + 1.asInstanceOf [T])
                                                  ^
```

```
addNumber1(100)  // result = 101
```

```
addNumber1(100.005) // result = 101.005
```

```
addNumber1("One :") // result = "One :1"
```

Any help please

Answer (score 4):

1st piece of advice: stay as far away from `asInstanceOf[]` as possible.  That's used as a way of sidestepping the type checker, which will lead to runtime errors.  The type checker is your friend.  Don't brush it off.

When the compiler sees the method `+` on an undefined type it assumes you were trying to do some kind of `String` operation.  Thus the confusing error message.

In order to add a number to a parameterized type you have to tell the compiler that the type is restricted to one of the `Numeric` types, and even then you are restricted in the operations that can be executed.

```
def addNumber1[T](x:T)(implicit ev: Numeric[T]):T = ev.plus(x, ev.one)
```

Note: This won't do `String` concatenation but all your number test cases should pass.

Note: `ev` for "evidence", i.e. if there is implicit evidence that `T` is `Numeric` then we can perform some math operations on it.

Comment: This won't support `addNumber1("One :") `. He will Need `TypeClasses` here

Comment: I think i understand asInstanceOf better with your responses. Sarvesh, Can i get any reference links to TypeClasses.

Comment: Sarvesh, Can this method be modified to support a string concatenation using TypeClasses.  Pointers please.. not looking for exact code..  many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this from a little different perspective: what, actually, *is* a parameter? What does it mean?

And let's start with something you are probably more familiar with: *value parameters*. What does a value parameter in a subroutine mean? Say, we have something like this:

```
def foo(a, b) = { /* … */ } // deliberately ignoring types and the body
```

It means: I have a subroutine `foo` with two parameters, `a` and `b`. And the subroutine is *general*, it doesn't care what the *actual* concrete values of `a` and `b` are. It works for *all* values of `a` and `b` because it doesn't even *know* what the values of `a` and `b` are.

A little more concrete:

```
def plus(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

Again, `plus` doesn't know what the actual values of `a` and `b` are. It works for `2` and `3` just as well as for `23` and `42` or `0` and `0`. It is completely and utterly ignorant of the concrete values of `a` and `b`. It only knows that `a` and `b` exist.

Now, *type parameters* are the same thing, just on the type level instead of the value level.

```
blabla[A]
```

means the same thing at the type level as `blabla(a)` means at the value level: "I have a thing, I have no idea what it is (and I don't care), but I'll call it `A`."

Now, let's look at your method:

```
def addNumber1[T](x: T): T = (x + 1.asInstanceOf[T])
```

So, what you have effectively done, is to tell Scala that you don't know anything about `T`. But then you do something with it (or rather with its instance): you add `1` to it. But, how do you even know you *can* add to it? You don't even know what it is! You have explicitly told the compiler: "I have some type, let's call it `T`, and that is all we know about that type." So, how do you know that the type even has a `+` method, if you don't know anything about it?

So, adding it *cannot* possibly work, it *must* fail!

However, the *way* it fails is slightly strange, and has to do with some of the pre-defined [implicit conversions]](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views) in the [`scala.Predef`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) object. In particular, [there is an implicit conversion for string concatenation, which can convert an arbitrary object into a `String` and then concatenate another `String` to it](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html#any2stringadd[A]extendsAnyVal). In this case, it converts `x` to an [`any2stringadd`](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) and then tries to add `1` (or rather `1` cast as an instance of `T`) to it, but the [`any2stringadd.+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html#+(other:String):String) method only takes a `String` as its argument, and thus you get the strange error message that it is expecting a `String`.

[Note that `any2stringadd` is [*deprecated* in Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L375-L383), so in the future you would just get an error about a non-existent method.]

There are a couple of other similar types that sometimes pop up, when you have complex type errors:

- [`Any`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any), [`AnyRef`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef), [`AnyVal`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyVal): these types sit at the very top of Scala's type hierarchy. Sometimes, when you have some programming error, where you think you are returning the same type from two different code paths, but you actually return two different types, Scala will nonetheless try to infer the common type between the two, and end up with the only common ancestor being `Any`, `AnyRef`, or `AnyVal`. (That would be kind of like `Object` in Java or C♯.)
- [`Serializable`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Serializable): this is actually the same thing as above. Lots of completely different types implement the `Serializable` interface, so sometimes when you have two very different types where you actually expect the same type, Scala will helpfully infer `Serializable` as the closest common ancestor, and then yell at you for doing stuff with a `Serializable` that it doesn't support.
- [`Product`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product) is a super-trait of all `Product`s (i.e. [`Product1`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product1), [`Product2`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product2), … [`Product22`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product22)) and thus all `Tuple`s (i.e. [`Tuple1`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple1), [`Tuple2`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple2), … [`Tuple22`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple22)). `Product` is also mixed into all `case class`es. So, if you have two `Tuple`s of different arity or two unrelated `case class`es (e.g. you sometimes return [`None`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.None$) but then accidentally return `somethingOfTypeFoo` instead of [`Some(somethingOfTypeFoo)`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Some)), then the most precise common type between [`Option`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option) and your `case class Foo` will be deduced as `Product` or …
- `Product with Serializable`: it is also possible to receive a combination of the above. E.g. `Tuple`s are `Serializable`, so *this* is actually the most precise common type of two `Tuple`s of different arity.

One common way to run into these problems is in a conditional expression without `else`:

```
if (true) 42
```

what type does this return? [`Int`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int)? No! The `then` branch returns `Int`, but the `else` branch returns *nothing* (because there is no `else` branch). Scala actually has a return type for not returning anything: [`Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit). `Unit` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, so the closest common ancestor of the types of the two branches of the conditional expression is actually `AnyVal`, not `Int`. (Note: the fact that the `else` branch is unreachable is irrelevant from a typing perspective. Reachability is a runtime thing, types are a compile time thing.)

So, how do we solve your problem? We need to tell the compiler that we actually *do* know a little bit about the type parameter. In particular, we know that it is some kind of "number". In Scala, there is a [typeclass](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) representing the abstract concept of "number", the [`scala.math.Numeric`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) typeclass. You can use it something like this:

```
def addNumber1[T : Numeric](x: T): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, implicitly[Numeric[T]].one)
```

This will work for everything that is "number-like":

```
addNumber1(100)     //=> 101
addNumber1(100.005) //=> 101.005
```

You, however, want to be more general:

```
addNumber1("One :")
// error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[String]
```

`String` is not an instance of the `Numeric` typeclass (it is not "number-like"). There is no ready-made typeclass in Scala that fits your bill. You will have to write your own or you may look at [Scalaz](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/) to see if there is something that fits your needs.

Comment: Appreciate taking the time to provide a detailed explanation. It helped me clear lot of things and specifically pointing me to  scala.Predef.

Comment: I understand context bounds are nice, but in this case I would prefer `ev` parameter over the much more verbose `implicitly[Numeric[T]]`.