# Scala Generic method errors on parameter operation

Tags: scala, generics

I get `"type mismatch; found : Int(1) required: String"` error when I try to return the incremented value of the input parameter from a Scala generic method below.

I did try using the Case method for this but it did not work as well. Basically I want to decide the operation based on input Type to the method and return the calculated/modified value.

```
object GenericOperations {

//  def increment[typ](val x:typ):typ = x match {
//    case _:Int => x + 1
//    case _:String => x + "x"
//  }

    def increment2(x:Any):Any = {
        if(x.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
          x+1
        }
        else if (x.isInstanceOf[String]) {
          x + "x"
        }
        else {
          println("No Match type")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of **Any**, `isInstanxeOf` checks, `asInstanceOf` casts, and the use of a print to signal an error are all code smells... I understand that you are probably learning and this is just for practice, but IMHO you should practice following the best practices of the language. What exactly did you want to make here? There are probably better solutions.

Comment: Hi Luis, Your assumption is correct, I'm just learning the language and trying to create a UDF for Spark job. My first attempt was try and achieve this with generic type (commented method). Solutions offered have helped clear the concepts for me.

Comment: Uhm, I do not know much about Spark UDFs, but I believe you are not allowed to use sophisticated things like **typeclasses** _(which would be the best solution for this problem)_. So I would either just go with overloading or leave the casts. Even if **Spark** is written in **Scala** and you use **Scala** to talk with **Spark**, they are generally two different worlds, so it may be worth asking this same question in the context of UDFs, maybe there is another way to handle this kind of scenarios in that world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `x` to be of type [`Any`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html). Which means you are only allowed to use the methods of `Any`.

You are calling `x.+(1)`. There is no `+` method in `Any`. Therefore, you can't use `+`.

You *should* be getting an error about `+` not existing, but you don't, so what's happening here?

There is an [implicit conversion](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views) for [string concatenation, which can convert an arbitrary object into a `String` and then concatenate another `String` to it](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html#any2stringadd[A]extendsAnyVal). In this case, it converts `x` to an [`any2stringadd`](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) and then tries to add `1` to it, but the [`any2stringadd.+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html#+(other:String):String) method only takes a `String` as its argument, and thus you get the strange error message that it is expecting a `String`.

You, however, are passing `1` as an argument, which is an `Int` not a `String`.

Note that `any2stringadd` is [*deprecated* in Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L375-L383), so in the future you would just get an error about a non-existent method.

Note that you have tagged this question with [generics](/questions/tagged/generics) and also talk about generics multiple times in the subject and the question body, yet *there are no generics* in your code. In fact, with generics, this problem would not exist.

See also

- [Scala Beginner trying to use Parameterised Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326056/2988)
- [Type parameter in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39295031/2988)

Comment: Thanks. This seems appropriate.

Comment: I just tried to cast it as Int to get around this.   x.asInstanceOf[Int] +1.  Is this a good practice? Do you also know why the commented increment method won't work?

Comment: Casts are *never* a good practice. They are also pretty much never required. The reason why your other method doesn't work is that you have declared `x` to be of an unknown type. Since the type is unknown, you can't use the `+` method, since you don't know whether the type that is passed in even *has* such a method.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use method overloading:

```
  def increment2(x: Int) = x + 1
  def increment2(x: String) = x + "x"
```

If you are sure you need exactly one function you may use `match`.

```
  def increment2(x: Any): Any = x match {
    case v: Int => v + 1
    case v: String => v + "x"
    case _ =>
      throw new Exception("No Match type")
  }
```

But returning `Any` isn't good thing as you cannot use its result without type cast

```
GenericOperations.increment2(3) + 3 // type mismatch
```

Still you may use the same `match` way:

```
  def increment2[T](x: T): T = (x match {
    case v: Int => v + 1
    case v: String => v + "x"
    case _ => throw new Exception("No Match type")
  }) match {
    case v: T => v
    case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid increment expression result type")
  }
```

As it has been mentioned in the comments there is also `typeclass` way:

```scala
//type class
trait Incrementable[T] {
  def inc(x: T): T
}

//type class instance for String
implicit val incString = new Incrementable[String] {
  def inc(x: String) = x + "x"
}

//type class instance for Int, single abstract method (SAM) form
implicit val incInt: Incrementable[Int] = (x: Int) => x + 1

def increment2[T: Incrementable](x: T): T = implicitly[Incrementable[T]].inc(x)
```

Comment: A **typeclass** would be a better implementation for this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've added typeclass example but I'm not sure I'm able to make a detailed explanation in English.

Comment: I would just quote Rob: https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this , even though I still don't like it because the usage of `getOrElse` , but here you go anyway:

```
    object GenericOperations {

    //  def increment[typ](val x:typ):typ = x match {
    //    case _:Int => x + 1
    //    case _:String => x + "x"
    //  }

        def increment2(x:Any):Any = {
            if(x.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
              toInt(x).getOrElse(0)+1
            }
            else if (x.isInstanceOf[String]) {
              x + "x"
            }
            else {
              println("No Match type")
            }
        }

        def toInt(x: Any): Option[Int] = x match {
          case i: Int => Some(i)
          case _ => None
        }
}
```